# Two functions with the same name in the same file | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a reaction roles in my discord bot.
But I do not want one reaction rolls, I want 2.. so I copied the code and just changed the message id, roles and reactions.
Because I use the same function name: "`on_raw_reaction_add`" only one of the reaction roles works. Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Here is my first reaction roles code:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messgae_id = payload.message_id
    if messgae_id == - - - - - - -:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        
        if payload.emoji.name == 'serverupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני שרת')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'botupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני בוטים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'library':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הספריה')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'dailyquestion':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='שאלה יומית')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'giveaways':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הגרלות')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'events':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='אירועים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'gif':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='גיף יומי')
    
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
```

Here is my second reaction roles code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messgae_id = payload.message_id
    if messgae_id == - - - - - - -:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        
        if payload.emoji.name == 'gryffindor':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' • גריפינדור')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'hufflepuff':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' • האפלפאף')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'ravenclaw':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' • רייבנקלו')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'slytherin':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' • סליתרין')
    
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
```

Comment: "Anyone have an idea how to fix this?"—rename one of the functions? Or possibly refactor this into one function since they're so similar?

Comment: @Chris `on_raw_reaction_add` is predefined in discord.py so he cannot rename it. The intended use is to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue you will have to add logic to include both function operations within the same `on_raw_reaction_add`. The point of the function `on_raw_reaction_add` is to trigger the program when a specific thing is done (reaction added), so you can't have more than one function, only logic within the function that determines which code to execute. (so you can have multiple operations but they must be triggered by the same function.)

For example, don't use something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if channel_id == general_channel_id
        pass #your code

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if channel_id == meme_channel_id
        pass #your code
```

instead combine them like so:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if channel_id == general_channel_id
        pass #your code
    if channel_id == meme_channel_id
        pass #your code
```

An example of how they can be combined in your case is:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messgae_id = payload.message_id
    #First operation
    if messgae_id == - - - - - - -: #first message id here
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        
        if payload.emoji.name == 'serverupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני שרת')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'botupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני בוטים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'library':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הספריה')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'dailyquestion':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='שאלה יומית')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'giveaways':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הגרלות')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'events':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='אירועים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'gif':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='גיף יומי')
    
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
    #Second operation
    if messgae_id == - - - - - - -: #second message id here
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        
        if payload.emoji.name == 'serverupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני שרת')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'botupdates':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='עדכוני בוטים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'library':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הספריה')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'dailyquestion':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='שאלה יומית')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'giveaways':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='הגרלות')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'events':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='אירועים')
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'gif':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='גיף יומי')
    
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
```

Also, I recommend you comment your code, it will be much easier to edit in this situations and easier for other people to understand in the future.